# Wordpress static index

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, custom-wordpress-pages

I have Wordpress installed on the root of the domain (*example.com*)

We are migrating it to "static pages" let's say HTML only. Because we are doing little by little, I only need the index page for now (*example.com/index.html*)

The problem is that all the posts are dependant on the index.php page. (*example.com/index.php?topic*)

I think I have some options:

**1.** On the htaccess file make a new rule (*Redirect 301 /index.php /index.html*) But I need some regular expressions to limit the line to explicitly index.php without any ?topic or anything. How can I limit this using regular expressions?

**2.** Change the configuration of WordPress so the root file is not index.php but, let's say *wordpress.php* and all themes are assembled from that file, therefore I have the *index.php* free.

**3.** I probably could throw all the website to a subdirectory, but I want to keep the URL of the posts as they are. So this is not a real option for me.

**The questions are:**

What regular expression can I try for Option 1?

Where can I change this "root file" *index.php* to *wordpress.php*?

Will any of those options viable? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a template for the posts so they don't depend on the index.php file. You can use single.php for the default 'post' post type.